# Convert string to float when the exponent is also a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

Converting a string to a float is easy when said string is 10E-3:

```
input_str = "10E-3"
output_float = float(input_str)
```

However, this breaks when the exponent is a non-integer. For instance:

```
input_str = "10E-3.5"
output_float = float(input_str)
```

returns:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10E-3.5'
```

How can I submit non-integer exponents?

Comment: How is this not duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As float() does not work with a non-integer exponent, do:

```
# Search for common exponent notation. 
notation = next(i for i in ["**", "E", "e"] if i in input_str)

# Split the input string based on the exponent.
mantissa, exponent = input_str.split(notation)

# Calculate the float.
output_float = float(mantissa) ** float(exponent)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  That's simply not how floating point notation works.  This is true in every language.

In code, you can do `10**-3.5`, but floating point constants always have an integer exponent.